# How to link with multiple DLLs exporting the same function(name)

Tags: dll, linker, llvm, dllimport

I am planning to write a little pascal-like frontend for LLVM (I'm working on Windows). Nothing for productive use but for toying around with LLVM. However there is one thing i can't wrap my head around. In (Object)Pascal languages you can write this in one Unit to import 2 functions with the same name from different libraries:

```
porcedure FooExecute; external 'Foo.dll' name 'Execute';
procedure BarExecute; external 'Bar.dll' name 'Execute';
```

By using an Alias in the code i can adress those functions correctly. However i don't get it, on how to solve this on the llvm+linker stage. Sofar i know, i need to generate an import library for the linker. That is not an issue. In theory i'd endup with Foo.a and Bar.a. However both import libraries would export "Execute" which does not match the used function names in my LLVM-Module. So in theory i need to assign the correct Symbol from my LLVM-Module to the correct symbol in the correct import library. It seems that a GNU-Linkerscript allows for this kind of mechanic but the LLVM Linker ld.lld.exe has no support for COFF and LLD-Link.exe has no support for linker scripts.

Suprisingly this kind of issue is very simple in Flat-Assembler(which i used in a toycompiler years ago) to solve, where you can wireup a SymbolName with an External SymbolName+LibraryName. So in theory i could use other tools to generate me some additional binaries i link with. However this does not seem to be the optimal way and requires platform manual work on asm-level.

So what is the ideal way to solve this kind of issue(given you can't modify the libraries you want to import, i.e. Windows-Libraries)

Comment: Your libraries are static (just *\*.lib*) or dynamic (*\*.lib* + *\*.dll*)? Are they built by *llvm*? Let's assume they can't be modified and you want to use them from some *Delphi* equivalent(also built with *llvm*)?. If they are dynamic, you could consider dynamic loading (loading them *manually* at runtime, and also loading the functions - which can become a pain if there are lots of them) with no linking whatsoever, if they are static, I think you'll get a linker error/warning, and not sure how to do it.

Comment: Dynamic loading (loadlibrary) is not an option since this is about linking and getting the correct information into the IDATA section of the coff.

Comment: Did you check [\[MSDN\]: /FORCE (Force File Output)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/force-force-file-output)?

Comment: Yes and this would not help Either since it just allows the linker to risk outputting unfinished binaries. Given a symbol like MessageBoxW is not resolved, it would not know which dll it belongs to, and therefore could not writ ethe required IData section